# Format sharepoint server time with javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, date-time

I retrieve  server date using javascript using JSLink like:

```
var currentServerDateTime = new Date(_spPageContextInfo.clientServerTimeDelta);
```

But I want it into format "dd/mm/yyyy", how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current date time try this code below :

```
var date = new Date();
var currentServerDateTime = date.format("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know how many milliseconds have elapsed since 1970, then JavaScript is outstanding. If you need formatted dates, then it can be kind of a pain. I think you'll find that lot's of people turn to other libraries, such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for this sort of thing.